# Show Child Div on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a timeline on my webpage that redraws based off the amount of events that are found in the DB. With each new event I clone box1 and rename some of the variables.

But for my onClick function the div holding the timeline information never shows. I think the issue might be the fact that the Id I am trying to show is surrounded in quotes so it is unable to find the div element id.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

```js
function showBox(clickedID) {
        var num = clickedID.split(/(\d+)/);
        var cardId ="card" + num[1];
    
        if ($(cardId).css('display') != 'none'){
          $(cardId).show();
        }else{
          $(cardId).hide();
        }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="box1" onclick="showBox(this.id)">
      <div id="card1" style="display:none">
          <time id="ticketNumberBox1"></time> <p id="shortDescriptionBox1"></p><p id="startDateBox1"></p>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: What sense does `if(condition) doX() else doX()` make? Also `$(cardId)` looks like you are using jQuery, yet your question has no jQuery tag.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: @connexo it is a mistake on my side. Fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var cardId ="card" + num[1];
```

should be

```
    var cardId ="#card" + num[1];
```

Instead of using `.show` and `.hide` you could also use `.toggle` but that's up to you.

---

as @connexo pointed out "the HTML presented by OP is invalid because the li does not have a ul or ol parent" so that is also changed inside of the snippet.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="box1" onclick="showBox(this.id)">k
  <div id="card1" style="display:none">asfadfsfd
      <time id="ticketNumberBox1"></time> <p id="shortDescriptionBox1"></p><p id="startDateBox1"></p>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showBox(clickedID) {
    var num = clickedID.split(/(\d+)/);
    var cardId ="#card" + num[1];

    if ($(cardId).css('display') != 'none'){
      $(cardId).hide();
    }else{
      $(cardId).show();
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Note** I added in random characters so it'd be easier to see/click.

Comment: Please point out that the HTML presented by OP is invalid because the `li` does not have a `ul` or  `ol` parent.